# Running a UiAutomator test via android app

Tags: android, jar, android-uiautomator

I have some test built, and my testing department can't figure out how to use the terminal. Uiautomator test are `.jar` files so must be ran via terminal. So for convenience, I want to make an app for them with the tests in a list to choose from to execute. Is this possible? My research leads me to believe that the devices will need to be rooted. If that is the case I will not be able to do it. So is there a workaround to this? This is what I have tried:

```
  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                Process process = rt.exec("su");
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());

                os.writeBytes("uiautomator runtest test.jar -c ui.test.getData\n");
                os.flush();

                os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                os.flush();
                process.waitFor();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This code will produce this :

```
  java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

Please help me with a way to get this to work. Thanks!

Comment: "Is this possible?" -- hopefully not, except on a rooted device, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare I understand. Do you have suggestions of something I could do to make it easy for my testing team to run a test of mine? Obviously other than rooting? If not, you should answer my question so I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have suggestions of something I could do to make it easy for my testing team to run a test of mine?

Create a desktop app that runs the test.

Or, just put a nice batch file/shell script in front of it. Perhaps one that launches the test and displays a photo of a cute kitten in the tester's Web browser.

(testers *love* cute kittens)

Or, set up a continuous integration server, so testers are not manually running the tests at all -- the tests are run automatically, and the testers are simply examining the results. I presume that somebody has a recipe for Hudson/Jenkins/whatever that can run an **`uiautomator`** test. And there may be a separate recipe for integrating photos of cute kittens into the test result reports, though it is possible that you'll be stuck writing your own for that.